# How to take Enter in UItextview swift

Tags: swift3, uitextview

I  have a UITextview in iphone app and I would like to have multiline text in it. There is no enter button like android to go to next line and iphone keyboard so how can I go to next line in UiTextView.

Comment: Whats the keyboard returnKeyType that you are using? If you don't change it it should be available by default for a UITextView

Answer (score 1):

There is something weird about it... I have a UITextView on my app and on my keyboard I can tap enter and skip a line.

Check out your TextView attribute inspector for the keyboard type (on mine is default), return key (also default) and auto-enable return key (on mine is not checked)